# Gwt datepicker translations

Tags: gwt, datepicker, localization

i'm using gwt datepicker and want to customize translations. For example I want to provide my own localization service and translate for example month names. Any idea how can I do it? I can't find any documentation how can i do this.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [GWT Documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html) You can change the locale of the Date Picker in the module.gwt.xml file, for example:

```
<!-- French in France -->
  <extend-property name="locale" values="fr_FR"/>
```

If you do not want to change the locale try [this](https://code.google.com/archive/p/gwt-datepicker/wikis/HowToUse.wiki) custom date picker

Comment: Yes, but i want to control displayed language programmatically. And gwt locale operates on  ?locale=? in address right?

Comment: Not necessarily in the address, you can set the locale from the html file like <meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=ja_JP"> but you should add it first to gwt.xml as described above. Please check the documentation: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleDefault